# How to setup mobile-first-cli to deploy on bluemix behind a corporate proxy

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I'm using Mobile Foundation on IBM Bluemix and I'm facing problems in setup IBM MobileFirst-CLI to deploy adapters and apps throw my corporate proxy.

In time, I'm on a macOS with the CLI version below:

```
mfpdev -v
8.0.0-2016070716
```

At this time, every time I have to interact with the server in have to connect to it using  my phone tethering. Please help, I'm running out of all my data plan.

The actual error:

```
$ mfpdev adapter deploy
Error: Cannot connect to server 'mfp-bluemix-dev' at 'https://xxxx-server.mybluemix.net:443'.
Reason: Missing runtime configuration details.: connect ECONNREFUSED 158.99.999.99:443
```

ps: address and ip of server obfuscated.

Best regards,
Bernardo Baumblatt.

Comment: What actual error are you seeing when you try to connect to the server through your corporate proxy?  If there is no connectivity to the server, you may have to ask your corporate IT team to allow access to the server's HTTP or HTTPS endpoint (by default, TCP port 9080 for HTTP, or port 9443 for HTTPS).

Comment: Hi Pat, thank you for your comment, question edited to include the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, MFP Dev CLI does not have the feature to configure a proxy. However, if all communications in your enterprise are routed through the corporate proxy, and the proxy can connect to IBM Bluemix, there should not be a problem.

You can submit a Request for Enhancement to add proxy feature to MFP Dev CLI.

Comment: Hi Vivin, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, we don't have such kind of routing configuration through corporate proxy, every service or software must have your own configurations. Ideally the MFP Dev CLI could get the npm or environment proxy definition to use in your comunication. If anyone have the same requirement, please vote for `RFE` [**here**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=107883).

Answer (score 0):

What Pat said in his comment is correct.  I suspect that you have two issues to address:

1. Your corporate proxy must allow access to your server's HTTP and HTTPS endpoints (9080 and 9443).  I've also heard of cases where the personal firewall on the individual's workstation has interfered.
2. You are running a VERY old version of the CLI.  Assuming your instance of Foundation Server on Bluemix isn't that old, you'll need to upgrade to interact with it properly.  I strongly suggest that you upgrade to the latest version via `npm -g install mfpdev-cli`.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for you answer.  (1) I don't think I having problems with the corporate proxy, I can use the Bluemix and MFP console on my browser without any issue. My question is, how config the proxy, I already tried export 'proxy' on OS environment and proxy config of npm.  (2) I agree with your point about the CLI version, but unfortunately I'm facing problems trying to update it on my Mac Sierra, but this is another issue.